# Convert seconds to minutes and seconds

Tags: python, string, time, tkinter

I've written some code in python 2.7 for a timer program. The downside is that the result is in seconds and I need it in `Minutes:Seconds`. I've tried to format the time to no avail. Can anyone help?"

```
from Tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()
root.title("Timer")
canvas = Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()

time=1

def tick():

    canvas.delete(ALL)
    global time
    time += 10


    if time >= 120:

        canvas.create_text(180,140, font = ("Calibri",200),text=time,fill='red')
    else:

        canvas.create_text(180,140, font = ("Calibri",200),text=time,fill='green')
    if time == 1000:
        time = 0
        tick()
    else:
        canvas.after(1000, tick)

def reset():
    global time
    time = 0

def close_window():
    root.destroy()

b = Button(root,text="Reset", command=reset)
c = Button(root,text="Quit", command=close_window) 
b.pack(side = LEFT)
c.pack(side = RIGHT)
canvas.after(1, tick)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use `datetime.timedelta`

```
import datetime
number_of_seconds = 1000
str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=number_of_seconds))

# output
'0:16:40'
```

Or even better since you only want `mm:ss`, you can use `time.strftime`

```
import time
number_of_seconds = 1000
time.strftime("%M:%S", time.gmtime(number_of_seconds))

# output
'16:40'
```

Documentations are available [for datetime module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html) and [for time module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/time.html).

Comment: Reg:  time.strftime: 
If number_of_seconds is more than 3600, then the output is completely incorrect

Answer (score 4):

To convert seconds into minutes and seconds, you can use the [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#divmod) function:

```
>>> time = 1000 # 1000 seconds
>>> divmod(1000, 60)
(16, 40)
>>>
```

The first number in the outputed tuple is the minutes and the second is the remaining seconds. You can then use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to make this tuple into the string you want:

```
>>> time = 1000
>>> '{}:{}'.format(*divmod(time, 60))
'16:40'
>>>
```

Comment: Works also if number of seconds > 3600

Comment: To have the values padded with zeroes use `'{0:02d}:{1:02d}'.format(*divmod(time, 60))`

Answer (score 4):

Being a somewhat-lazy programmer, I like to reuse good work that's embodied in the standard library (where it might well get optimized and is surely very well tested).  So...:

```
import datetime
def secs_to_MS(secs):
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(secs).strftime('%M:%S')
```

If you need to have hours there as well, that's easy too:

```
import datetime
def secs_to_HMS(secs):
    if secs < 3600:
        return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(secs).strftime('%M:%S')
    else:
        return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(secs).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```